# необходимо ли указывать кавычки в наименовании компании

Tags: кавычки

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как орфографически правильно написать следующую фразу?

> Приглашаем Вас на вебинары компании Звездочка

или

> Приглашаем Вас на вебинары компании "Звездочка".

Причем Звездочка имеет юридическую форму как ООО "Звездочка". В юр. форме приглашение делать по рядку причин нельзя.
Буду очень признательна, если вы укажете, каким конкретно правилом это регламентируется. Спасибо!

Comment: Любовь, писать "Вы" (с большой буквы), обращаясь к неопределённому читателю или кругу читателей, дурной тон. И делать ударение на этом местоимении устно — тоже.

Answer (score 1):

По Розенталю, 60-й параграф, кавычками выделяются:

названия фабрик, заводов, шахт, рудников, судов, гостиниц, организаций и т. д.: фабрика «Женская мода»; завод «Богатырь»; типография «Оригинал»; шахта «Северная 2-бис»; станция метро «Театральная»; теплоход «Александр Пушкин»; броненосец «Потёмкин»; крейсер «Аврора»; гостиница «Метрополь»; издательство «Просвещение»; спортивное общество «Динамо»; трест «Нефтегазстрой»; управление «Проектстроймеханизация»; концерн «Дженерал моторз корпорейшн»; фирма «Заря»; АО «Конверсия»; киностудия «Мосфильм»; кинотеатр «Космос»; театр «Ла Скала»; музыкальная труппа «Театро музикале делла Читта ди Рома»; телевизионная компания «Коламбия бродкастинг систем».